React-native ./gradlew clean bundle error Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'
I try to add android.applicationVariants in build.gradle. but getting error with Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'  - Unmatched attributes:
def extractFinFile(zip, variant, destFileName) {
    copy {
        from zip.matching { include 'guardit.fin' }
        into "${buildDir}/outputs/fin/${variant.name}"
        rename { filename ->
            filename.replace 'guardit4j', "${destFileName}"
        }
    }
}

def extractFinFiles() {
    android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->
        if (android.hasProperty("dynamicFeatures")) {
            def rootProjectName = project.rootProject.name
            android.dynamicFeatures.each { String featureProjectName ->
                def dynamicFeatureProject = project.rootProject.project(featureProjectName)
                if (!dynamicFeatureProject.hasProperty("android")) {
                    // Android configuration is not accessible during project configuration
                    return
                }

                def applicationVariant = dynamicFeatureProject.android.applicationVariants.find { applicationVariant ->
                    applicationVariant.name == variant.name
                }

                if (!applicationVariant) {
                    return
                }

                def compileConfiguration = applicationVariant.compileConfiguration
                compileConfiguration.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies.each { dependency ->
                    // This checks whether dependency is an application module itself
                    if (dependency.moduleGroup == rootProjectName && dependency.moduleName == project.name) {
                        return
                    }

                    dependency.moduleArtifacts.each { artifact ->
                        File dependencyFile = artifact.file
                        if (dependencyFile.name.endsWith(".aar")) {
                            def aarZip = zipTree(dependencyFile)
                            extractFinFile(aarZip, variant, dependencyFile.name.substring(0, dependencyFile.name.lastIndexOf('.')))
                            aarZip.files.each { fileFromAar ->
                                if (fileFromAar.name == "classes.jar") {
                                    def classesJarZip = zipTree(fileFromAar)
                                    extractFinFile(classesJarZip, variant, dependencyFile.name.substring(0, dependencyFile.name.lastIndexOf('.')))
                                }
                            }
                        } else if (dependencyFile.name.endsWith(".jar")) {
                            def jarZip = zipTree(dependencyFile)
                            extractFinFile(jarZip, variant, dependencyFile.name.substring(0, dependencyFile.name.lastIndexOf('.')))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

       def files = variant.compileConfiguration.files
       files.each { file ->
           println file.name
           if (file.name.endsWith(".aar") ) {
               def aarZip = zipTree(file)
               extractFinFile(aarZip, variant, file.name.substring(0, file.name.lastIndexOf('.')))
               aarZip.files.each { fileFromAar ->
                   if (fileFromAar.name == "classes.jar") {
                       def classesJarZip = zipTree(fileFromAar)
                       extractFinFile(classesJarZip, variant, file.name.substring(0, file.name.lastIndexOf('.')))
                   }
               }
           } else 
        if (file.name.endsWith(".jar")) {
               def jarZip = zipTree(file)
               extractFinFile(jarZip, variant, file.name.substring(0, file.name.lastIndexOf('.')))
           }
       }
    }
}

i got error when run command ./gradlew clean bundle
 > The consumer was configured to find a component for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :react-native-firebase_messaging:
       - Configuration ':react-native-firebase_messaging:debugApiElements' variant android-classes-jar declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
           - Unmatched attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
               - Provides attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-classes-jar' but the consumer didn't ask for it
               - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'debug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
               - Provides its elements packaged as a jar but the consumer didn't ask for it
       - Configuration ':react-native-firebase_messaging:debugApiElements' variant android-lint declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
           - Unmatched attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
               - Provides attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-lint' but the consumer didn't ask for it
               - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'debug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
               - Provides its elements packaged as a jar but the consumer didn't ask for it
       - Configuration ':react-native-firebase_messaging:debugApiElements' variant android-lint-local-aar declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
           - Unmatched attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
               - Provides attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-lint-local-aar' but the consumer didn't ask for it
               - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'debug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
       - Configuration ':react-native-firebase_messaging:debugApiElements' variant android-lint-model-metadata declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
           - Unmatched attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
               - Provides attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-lint-model-metadata' but the consumer didn't ask for it
               - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'debug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
       - Configuration ':react-native-firebase_messaging:debugApiElements' variant android-lint-variant-dependencies-model declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
           - Unmatched attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
               - Provides attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-lint-variant-dependencies-model' but the consumer didn't ask for it
               - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'debug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
       - Configuration ':react-native-firebase_messaging:debugApiElements' variant android-lint-variant-dependencies-partial-results declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
           - Unmatched attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
               - Provides attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-lint-variant-dependencies-partial-results' but the consumer didn't ask for it
               - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'debug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
       - Configuration ':react-native-firebase_messaging:debugApiElements' variant android-manifest declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
           - Unmatched attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
               - Provides attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-manifest' but the consumer didn't ask for it
               - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'debug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
       - Configuration ':react-native-firebase_messaging:debugApiElements' variant android-renderscript declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
           - Unmatched attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
               - Provides attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-renderscript' but the consumer didn't ask for it
               - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'debug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
       - Configuration ':react-native-firebase_messaging:debugApiElements' variant android-symbol-with-package-name declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
           - Unmatched attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
               - Provides attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-symbol-with-package-name' but the consumer didn't ask for it
               - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'debug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
       - Configuration ':react-native-firebase_messaging:debugApiElements' variant jar declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug':
           - Unmatched attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
               - Provides attribute 'artifactType' with value 'jar' but the consumer didn't ask for it
               - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'debug' but the consumer didn't ask for it
               - Provides its elements packaged as a jar but the consumer didn't ask for it

i use gradle 8.7
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip

java version 17
java 17.0.10 2024-01-16 LTS
i need help to solve this problem
